# Is createStratergy a function?

Tags: passport.js, passport-local

```
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
                  ^

TypeError: User.createStrategy is not a function
```

I dont know like docs has it repo has it .. But I get it even after installing latest packages of passport and imported them .

Answer (score 0):

Are you exporting createStrategy function from User class? In general passport.use will have two parameters(name,strategy). This strategy will be based on the idp you are using.